# AspNetCore NullReferenceException on calculated fields

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

I have some models with calculated fields that work correctly to display values but I get a NullReferenceException when I try to Edit an entry or Create a new entry.

Model:

```
public class MMSPostage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pieces")]
    public int PieceCount { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C3}")]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C3}")]
    [Display(Name = "Total")]
    public decimal MMSSubTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return (Rate + JobType.Cost) * PieceCount;
        }
    }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
}
```

Edit page that throws NullReferenceException when saving includes:

```
MMSPostage = await _context.MMSPostage
            .Include(m => m.JobType)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Context Model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("SPM_Postage_Billing.Models.MMSPostage", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("ID")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.Property<int>("PieceCount");

                    b.Property<decimal>("Rate");

                    b.HasKey("ID");

                    b.HasIndex("JobTypeID");

                    b.ToTable("MMSPostage");
                });
```

SQL:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_MMSPostage_JobType_JobTypeID] FOREIGN KEY ([JobTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[JobType] ([ID]) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MMSPostage_JobTypeID]
    ON [dbo].[MMSPostage]([JobTypeID] ASC);
```

Error:

> SPM_Postage_Billing.Models.MMSPostage.get_MMSSubTotal() in
>   MMSPostage.cs
>   +
>                   return (Rate + JobType.Cost) * PieceCount; Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter(Func getter, object target)

This is hopefully something simple I am overlooking. I am sort of new to AspNetCore so any help is appreciated big time!

Comment: I see there is a relationship between `JobType` and `MMSPostage`. You need to show us how you configured the relationship via `EF Core` I assume? The exception definitely looks like `JobType` is being NULL (where you did `JobType.Cost`).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. In SQL I have a foreign key relationship that was set up using EF Core. 
CONSTRAINT [FK_MMSPostage_JobType_JobTypeID] FOREIGN KEY ([JobTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[JobType] ([ID]) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity("SPM_Postage_Billing.Models.MMSPostage", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("ID")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.Property<int>("PieceCount");

                    b.Property<decimal>("Rate");

                    b.HasKey("ID");

                    b.HasIndex("JobTypeID");

                    b.ToTable("MMSPostage");
                });

Comment: Can you post that up in the OP instead in the comment? It's hard to read.

Comment: yes of course, my mistake

Comment: I don't see you setup relationship between `JobType` and `MMSPostage` on the entity configuration. And what's up with all those hard-coded magic strings there?

Comment: Hi David, I will try to implement the solution you provided. I would like to know what magic strings you are referring to. Is this an example of one? `b.Property<int>("PieceCount");` as this was generated by EF.

Comment: yes that was the magic string I referred to. they were generated by EF? Are you using a Reverse Engineering Tool to generate models from an existing database?!!

Comment: No I created the model classes and used EF Core to create the db

Comment: I see, then you don't need to copy and paste the code auto generated from `Snapshot.cs`. Instead, you should show how you configure those model classes and their relationships, supposedly in `OnModelCreating()` in your `DbContext` class. By the way, my post is exactly doing the CodeFirst with Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between `JobType` and `MMSPostage` is just one-to-many, i.e., 1 `MMSPostage` has 1 `JobType` and 1 `JobType` has many `MMSPostage`s, then you can set things up like the following:

**Note:**

- I like to separate the persistence models from domain models. So I have 2 sets of models in my application (beside view models).
- This is using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` v2.0.3. For v2.1.x where the lazy loading feature is back, the entities might look different as you might need the `virtual` keyword there.

#### JobTypeEntity.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Persistence.EFCore.Entities
{
    public class JobTypeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }

        public List<MMSPostageEntity> MMSPostages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### MMSPostageEntity.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Persistence.EFCore.Entities
{
    public MMSPostageEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PieceCount { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }

        public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
        public JobTypeEntity JobType { get; set; }

        public double SubTotal
        {
            get
            {
               return (Rate + JobType.Cost) * PieceCount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to configure entity properties to SQL table columns, either using Data Annotations or Fluent API. You can do it directly on `OnModelCreating()` like you did or you create configuration class for each entity and apply the configurations there.

#### JobTypeConfiguration.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Persistence.EFCore.Configurations
{
    public class JobTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobTypeEntity>
    {
        public void Configure<EntityTypeBuilder<JobTypeEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
            builder.Property(x => x.Cost).IsRequired();

            builder.ToTable("JobType");
        }
    }
}
```

#### MMSPostageConfiguration.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Persistence.EFCore.Configurations
{
    public class MMSPostageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MMSPostageEntity>
    {
        public void Configure<EntityTypeBuilder<MMSPostageEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            // By default, public properties with getter and setter
            // will be included!
            // Since the computed property SubTotal only has getter,
            // it should not be included by default.
            // Just in case you worry about, you can do Ignore() too!
            builder.Ignore(x => x.SubTotal);

            // This is how you configure the 1-to-many relationship!
            builder.HasOne(x => x.JobType)
                .WithMany(jt => jt.MMSPostages)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.JobTypeId);

            builder.ToTable("MMSPostage");
        }
    }
}
```

#### AppDbContext.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Persistence.EFCore
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public class AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // You apply those configurations
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobTypeConfiguration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MMSPostageConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<JobTypeEntity> JobTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MMSPostageEntity> MMSPostages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then on your edit page, you should be able to grab the `MMSPostageEntity` from the database, including the `JobTypeEntity`, and construct a view model for it.

#### PostageController.cs

```
namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class PostageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

        public PostageController(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
           _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var postageEntity = _dbContext.MMSPostages
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(x => x.JobType)
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (postageEntity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Then you can construct your view model here!
            // Don't send your db entities directly to views man!
            var vm = new EditPostageViewModel
            {
                PostageId = postageEntity.Id,
                PieceCount = postageEntity.PieceCount,
                Rate = postageEntity.Rate,
                SubTotal = postageEntity.SubTotal,
                JobType = postageEntity.JobType.Name
            };

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I wrote everything as examples by hand hence they're not tested and might not even compiled.